# Azure Policy to Audit if NSGs contain a rule where Source and Destination match and are both IP addresses

Tags: azure, azure-networking, network-security-group, azure-policies

I'm trying to create an azure policy that audits my NSGs.

I need to verify if my NSGs contain a rule where the source and destination match and are both IP addresses (so not "Virtual Machine")

I currently have the following:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*]",
            "where": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].sourcePortRange",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].destinationPortRange",
                  "equals": "*"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].sourceAddressPrefix",
                  "match": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].destinationAddressPrefix"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].destinationAddressPrefix",
                  "match": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].sourceAddressPrefix"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].access",
                  "equals": "Allow"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules[*].direction",
                  "equals": "Inbound"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "notEquals": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "audit"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

However this says that all my NSGs are non compliant, even though I know some of them are.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance